# How to clean my Mac from malware like ps4ux

Tags: macos

only been using it for 2 months. (OS X El Capitan 10.11.4) I'm creating web application using Ruby on Rails. I know it is a bad thing to find a cracked installer with license so, I got my karma. i was searching for a Rubymine license because i'm using Sublime. 
When I searched for a license I found this website:

```
http://warezfileshere.me/sofware/rubymine-license-key-keygen.html
```

So I installed the apps and nothing happened but my browser was always redirect me in this site:

```
http://ps4ux.com/click?h=Ax722bagzrl8Vk3_frrT0FPvs0OX4u2wcw-CZ0O4YnvDYH1wjKXE4iV9P95-WidXJPKiD812ZxRTjI8Qx1BL9WAfhPBAA4nvNYpjf-AoA4ejDT8vvexcesyw7q_qR_pMPbfLAdUg3tQypcwz3gl-bKhrw3c-Ramb9bSnlqQTZu9r2VGZmBI5nlhHftqW8RDVrTOfb2YhTxW2gDB9GaAMbJnU0oTGij8m8o67Dz4xhQe4JNJdDZbdSmgq36DUOzlIVIJPv5I0RsuTuYAtPcQdMhEK_RrtYLfIoVpxrbI5cbSA3GAPP2SxJXgXWPfYQBlnPpTkK5efW7DHCOzWJvyKPQfmjtxKlS_sH5a6c8RJJvvu2nQSW8PE5F-UTdbcxAlAZR0_sjuG11DW0kQ0HjcuU1IJCzxTLyU6YnGwjnfDlj7bSuEQNXMS7bh1o1WVlAGkpvYQR2MQMu_ql93KYvcR46waJWV_qn9GevqQHRNlBiLhs1US4EBcZQ-xkvunmUVt31VKfAtTN8ADu9NHg5Uli71psw52-rhFlG8xVdCC6KJ66oSdNkoPJZwNGXMHT_CYciKLX9KF8U3fiy0nMmgLxG4hFfL83svXuM2Gjumv6qEpMjNm2dnvnrjK4rAAjrVo0batWO5DZLusvb008B-0CGzDHQ6XMxwbnu_NQHJ87LZwLqbHArlc2_c4PmFc8_6NLUvciqusbCv-Lc4IOpbzNZsZf3LkLH5rKCVGJygTySJcBtC8xoz9QoGESRfZXPepQgt0yocZnQxP4MyLSYzgWz-FNAmGVpjje5ez-JyMnQhr1oPZmlx2Qdh75rgB-vpGIycVePZ4UkE&subid=g-88322244-b77466937d0641a891fcdbdd16c020f7-&data_test=2016082307_t&data_fb=no&data_rtt=0&data_proto=https%3A&data_ic=false&data_ss=732x1280
```

I didn't know what that was so I search for ps4ux and  found out that is  malware.

Then, when I'm working on  my project, Chrome gives me this
[image]

I don't know where they came from. Please, someone help me! I learned my lesson:  don't ever search for or use a cracked license..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the apps that can help here is [malwarebytes](https://malwarebytes.com/antimalware/mac/). It's free to use for 14 days and seems to work for the ps4ux problem.

Comment: Another tip: get littlesnitch (https://www.obdev.at/products/littlesnitch/index.html) must have if you want to upgrade your security vs malware. Was my first purchased mac software.

Answer (score 0):

One of the best AV/Anti-Malware utilities I have used is [Avast](https://www.avast.com/free-mac-security).  The product is free for Mac users (Windows and Linux require purchase) but it uses the same detection technology.